# Getting compile error in dynamic import from shared in next app

Tags: webpack, next.js, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspace to setup multiapp SPA, In that I have one folder which will share common components like header, footer etc. I am getting compile error if I am trying to use component from shared directory.

```
Failed to compile.

../core/components/hoc/Layout.js 11:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export default function Layout(props) {
|   return (
>     <div style={layoutStyle}>
|       <Header />
|       {props.children}

> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

dependencies in package.json file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^3.0.2",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was transpile issue because next expects component in transpilled format.